# Adding exports to ~/.bashrc

Tags: bash, terminal, flow-project

I'm working on installing the flow-project and I'm getting a message to add some things into my bashrc. Not sure if it matters but I'm on macOS.

This is the message it reads: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbP3j.png

```
~/flow
Add the following to your ~/.bashrc:

export SUMO_HOME="$HOME/sumo_binaries/bin"
export PATH="$SUMO_HOME:$PATH"
```

I've looked in other threads too, I've added it manually as well as the "echo >> ~/.bashrc" method. It's definitely in the txt file. Thanks!

Edit: Question wasn't made clear, but I have tried putting the export ... into my .bashrc file but the thing I'm trying to install doesn't recognize that I've done that.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've tried putting the following commands into my .bashrc file but I don't think my installation recognizes it.

Comment: How did you test? Did you start a new window? Are you sure your terminal is _actually using bash_ as it shell? (That latter is important: MacOS uses zsh by default now; the corresponding file is `.zshrc`).

Comment: Don't add environment variables to `.bashrc` (`.zshrc`) anyway; add them to `.bash_profile` (`.zprofile`).

Comment: Okay thanks for the infos! I've put the following commands into my .zprofile, but to my demise it still doesn't recognize it. I get the same prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Verify what's exported with:

```
export -p
```

as per help

```
export: export [-nf] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
    NAMEs are marked for automatic export to the environment of
    subsequently executed commands.  If the -f option is given,
    the NAMEs refer to functions.  If no NAMEs are given, or if `-p'
    is given, a list of all names that are exported in this shell is
    printed.  An argument of `-n' says to remove the export property
    from subsequent NAMEs.  An argument of `--' disables further option
    processing.
```

Comment: When I run this I see a long list of exports. I see export `SUMO_HOME=/Users/name/sumo` but it doesn't match what I put: the sumo_binaries to bin.

Comment: Then, verify you are using bash, logout and login again, close and reopen your terminal again or reboot